# Change hint text on AppCompatEditText at runtime?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

Has anyone figured out a way to change the hint text (the text displayed when the field is empty) at runtime instead of in the layout?
The layout looks like this:

> ```
>       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>           style="@style/CreateAccount.Zip.Label">
>           <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
>               android:id="@+id/Zip"
>               style="@style/CreateAccount.Zip" />
>       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
> ```

The problem I have is that the Material Design field label animation gets broken if I set it at runtime :-(
It just stays static if I set it at runtime...no motion at all when you start typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the `TextInputLayout` hint:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_text_input_layout);
textInputLayout.setHint("New hint");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:hint="Front tire" in you xml.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/tireodo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editWidthLayout"
                        android:hint="Front Tire"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
```